# How to assign pay period numbers for given start date and end date

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a table with the start and end dates of pay periods.

- The period length (days) isn't static. It ranges from 0 to 24.
- The number of pay periods could be 24-28 for a given year.
- The only thing fixed is the first start date is 12/31/2000, and the next
  start date is right after the previous end date, e.g. 1st end date =
  1/13/2001, 2nd start date = 1/14/2001.
- When the time progresses, new pay periods are added to the table.

I need to assign pay period number for a given calendar year. The rule is the period include January 1 is period 1 even though its start date is December in the previous year. For example, 1/31/2000-1/13/2001 should be period 1 for the year 2001. When next year's January 1 is included in the pay period, period 1 of next year starts (12/30/2001-1/12/2002 is Pay Period 1 for 2002).

I need to create a query for PostgreSQL or PostgreSQL function. I want to assign period 1 to the youngest date in the target year and increment pay period number till pay period reaches 28 or calendar year ends (before 1/1 of next year). I'm not sure about my logic and the part in a SELECT statement where I used calendar_pp which doesn't exist in the table.

Start    End

```
1/14/2001    1/27/2001<br/>
1/28/2001    2/10/2001<br/>
2/11/2001    2/24/2001<br/>
2/25/2001    3/10/2001<br/>
3/11/2001    3/24/2001<br/>
3/25/2001    4/7/2001<br/>
4/8/2001    4/21/2001<br/>
4/22/2001    5/5/2001<br/>
5/6/2001    5/19/2001<br/>
5/20/2001    6/2/2001<br/>
6/3/2001    6/16/2001<br/>
6/17/2001    6/30/2001<br/>
7/1/2001    7/14/2001<br/>
7/15/2001    7/28/2001<br/>
7/29/2001    8/11/2001<br/>
8/12/2001    8/25/2001<br/>
8/26/2001    9/8/2001<br/>
9/9/2001    9/22/2001<br/>
9/23/2001    9/30/2001<br/>
10/1/2001    10/6/2001<br/>
10/7/2001    10/20/2001<br/>
10/21/2001    11/3/2001<br/>
11/4/2001    11/17/2001<br/>
11/18/2001    12/1/2001<br/>
12/2/2001    12/15/2001<br/>
12/16/2001    12/29/2001<br/>
12/30/2001    1/12/2002<br/>
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calendar_pp(end_date DATE) 
RETURNS TABLE (
start_date_col DATE,
end_date_col DATE,
calendar_pp INTEGER) 
AS $$

DECLARE
calendar_pp INTEGER ; 
counter INTEGER := 0 ;
start_date DATE := TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(begin_payperiod_date,'MM/DD/YY'),'MM/DD') ;
end_date_year INTEGER := CAST((TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(min(end_payperiod_date),'MM/DD/YY'),'YYYY')) AS INTEGER) ;
target_year INTEGER := 2001 ; --1st pay period = 12/31/2000-1/13/2001

BEGIN
    WHILE counter <= 28 LOOP --max pay period = 28
        counter := counter + 1 ; 
        calendar_pp := calendar_pp + 1 ; 
        end_date_year := end_date_year + 1 ;
        target_year := target_year + 1 ;

    --assign pay period starting with 1 till end_date becomes next year
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT TO_DATE(begin_payperiod_date,'MM/DD/YY'), TO_DATE(end_payperiod_date,'MM/DD/YY'), calendar_pp
    FROM actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years
    WHERE end_date_year = target_year AND calendar_pp is null
    order by TO_DATE(begin_payperiod_date,'MM/DD/YY')
END LOOP; 

END; $$

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

This is the expected results.

Start    End    Pay Period

```
1/14/2001    1/27/2001    2<br/>
1/28/2001    2/10/2001    3<br/>
2/11/2001    2/24/2001    4<br/>
2/25/2001    3/10/2001    5<br/>
3/11/2001    3/24/2001    6<br/>
3/25/2001    4/7/2001    7<br/>
4/8/2001    4/21/2001    8<br/>
4/22/2001    5/5/2001    9<br/>
5/6/2001    5/19/2001    10<br/>
5/20/2001    6/2/2001    11<br/>
6/3/2001    6/16/2001    12<br/>
6/17/2001    6/30/2001    13<br/>
7/1/2001    7/14/2001    14<br/>
7/15/2001    7/28/2001    15<br/>
7/29/2001    8/11/2001    16<br/>
8/12/2001    8/25/2001    17<br/>
8/26/2001    9/8/2001    18<br/>
9/9/2001    9/22/2001    19<br/>
9/23/2001    9/30/2001  20<br/>
10/1/2001    10/6/2001  21<br/>
10/7/2001    10/20/2001 22<br/>
10/21/2001    11/3/2001 23<br/>
11/4/2001    11/17/2001 24<br/>
11/18/2001    12/1/2001 25<br/>
12/2/2001    12/15/2001 26<br/>
12/16/2001    12/29/2001    27<br/>
12/30/2001    1/12/2002 1<br/>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure that your question [clearly defines the problem that you are having and the steps that you have taken to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Post the definition of the table actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years as this appears to be the heart of your requirement. If it's not then what is? Also, post sample data from that table and expected results from that data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the 28 requirement.  Are you saying that the pay period should reset even if we aren't near Jan 1?  Assuming that's not true, I think this should work:

```
with dates as (SELECT start_date, end_date
  FROM (VALUES
('12/31/2000'::date,'1/13/2001'::date),
('1/14/2001','1/27/2001'),
('1/28/2001','2/10/2001'),
('2/11/2001','2/24/2001'),
('2/25/2001','3/10/2001'),
('3/11/2001','3/24/2001'),
('3/25/2001','4/7/2001'),
('4/8/2001','4/21/2001'),
('4/22/2001','5/5/2001'),
('5/6/2001','5/19/2001'),
('5/20/2001','6/2/2001'),
('6/3/2001','6/16/2001'),
('6/17/2001','6/30/2001'),
('7/1/2001','7/14/2001'),
('7/15/2001','7/28/2001'),
('7/29/2001','8/11/2001'),
('8/12/2001','8/25/2001'),
('8/26/2001','9/8/2001'),
('9/9/2001','9/22/2001'),
('9/23/2001','9/30/2001'),
('10/1/2001','10/6/2001'),
('10/7/2001','10/20/2001'),
('10/21/2001','11/3/2001'),
('11/4/2001','11/17/2001'),
('11/18/2001','12/1/2001'),
('12/2/2001','12/15/2001'),
('12/16/2001','12/29/2001'),
('12/30/2001','1/12/2002')
) v (start_date, end_date)
)
select start_date, end_date, rank() OVER (partition by date_trunc('year', end_date) ORDER BY end_date) FROM dates;
 start_date |  end_date  | rank
------------+------------+------
 2000-12-31 | 2001-01-13 |    1
 2001-01-14 | 2001-01-27 |    2
 2001-01-28 | 2001-02-10 |    3
 2001-02-11 | 2001-02-24 |    4
 2001-02-25 | 2001-03-10 |    5
 2001-03-11 | 2001-03-24 |    6
 2001-03-25 | 2001-04-07 |    7
 2001-04-08 | 2001-04-21 |    8
 2001-04-22 | 2001-05-05 |    9
 2001-05-06 | 2001-05-19 |   10
 2001-05-20 | 2001-06-02 |   11
 2001-06-03 | 2001-06-16 |   12
 2001-06-17 | 2001-06-30 |   13
 2001-07-01 | 2001-07-14 |   14
 2001-07-15 | 2001-07-28 |   15
 2001-07-29 | 2001-08-11 |   16
 2001-08-12 | 2001-08-25 |   17
 2001-08-26 | 2001-09-08 |   18
 2001-09-09 | 2001-09-22 |   19
 2001-09-23 | 2001-09-30 |   20
 2001-10-01 | 2001-10-06 |   21
 2001-10-07 | 2001-10-20 |   22
 2001-10-21 | 2001-11-03 |   23
 2001-11-04 | 2001-11-17 |   24
 2001-11-18 | 2001-12-01 |   25
 2001-12-02 | 2001-12-15 |   26
 2001-12-16 | 2001-12-29 |   27
 2001-12-30 | 2002-01-12 |    1
(28 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Jeremy. As I have more data, I modified the query as: `with dates as (SELECT start_date, end_date FROM (SELECT  to_date(begin_payperiod_date, 'MM/DD/YY'), to_date(end_payperiod_date, 'MM/DD/YY') from actacc.payperiod_conversion_all_years order by begin_payperiod_date) v (start_date, end_date)
)
select start_date, end_date, rank() OVER (partition by date_trunc('year', end_date) ORDER BY end_date) FROM dates;`

Comment: Yes, that's right, I just put the dates in the CTE to avoid creating a table, but you would normally select them from a table.  So, did this answer your question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome.  It would be great if you could select this as the answer so this question isn't still marked as unanswered.